# React-Native 0.59 / Babel / Jest failures

Tags: react-native, jestjs, babeljs

dealing with babel / jest issues while upgrading to RN 0.59.10 from 0.52. any help, specific or directional, is appreciated.

our tests passed at RN 0.52. i'm hoping these are configuration issues more than structural ones.

problem: call/constructor errors. several tests fail on super calls in deps (like RN's EventEmitter), or new new calls (the resulting objects are undefined).

example:

```
test suite failed to run
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
      at new RCTDeviceEventEmitter (node_modules/react-native/Libraries/EventEmitter/RCTDeviceEventEmitter.js:53:5)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/react-native/Libraries/EventEmitter/RCTDeviceEventEmitter.js:84:18)
      at Object.require (node_modules/react-native/Libraries/EventEmitter/NativeEventEmitter.js:15:31)
```

our jest config in package.json looks like:

```
"jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "automock": true,
    "setupFiles": ["<rootDir>/jest/setup.js"],  
    "transform": { "^.+\\.jsx?$": "babel-jest" },  
    ...
```

our (relevant) deps in package.json are

```
    "@babel/core": "^7.5.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.5.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-function-bind": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-destructuring": "^7.5.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-flow-strip-types": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-flow": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "7.5.0",

    "jest": "24.8.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.55.0",
```

our babel.config.json uses

`'module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'`

as the preset.

Answer (score 0):

I had same kind of issues when updating to 0.59. I noticed that tests failed that used `jest.enableAutomock();`. I just removed that line and updated my mock setups and test passed again. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can add following line in `babel.config.js`

```
plugins: ['@babel/plugin-transform-flow-strip-types']
```